# Redirect to HTTPS except 1 page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Been looking all over for an answer but no response found could solve my problem.
I'm using the following .htaccess file to redirect users from a site to its https version :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api-vop/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have first a rule to redirect to HTTPS then a rewrite rule for classic url rewriting to replace urls like myfile.php to /my-file

Thing is I need to let one url which is http://my-server.com/api-vop go through without being redirected to https, as seen by this line :

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api-vop/
```

Thing is I cannot get it to work, at best I'm trhown back to the index.php page.

Any solution anyone ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Keep your first rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api-vop/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L,NE]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm afraid you lost me there with 2 things : THE_REQUEST and the NE in the last line. Could you maybe post the exact line I'm supposed to use ? Again there is non php file called but a symbolic url which is my-server.com/api-vop

Comment: Rule that I provided you here is what you need to use. You need to **replace** your first rule with this rule i.e. all lines above `RewriteBase /`.